# C# Progression Path

Tags: c#, coding-style

I have been using C#  for almost 3 months now. I wanted to know what are the steps involved in making of a efficient and clever C# programmer. As there are a lot of professional programmers on SO who have tons of experience on working with the .Net Framework and C#, I want to ask them that what is the correct path through which if you go with patience and hard work, you can become from a C# beginner to a C# Expert.
I really want to improve my stature from a beginner C# Programmer to a expert or a Guru. I hope that the answers to this question will also help other C# Programmers both new as well as experienced ones..
Basically what I am expecting from the experts is a list of things like:-

- You should do unit testing
- You should learn about the basic data structures like Lists or Dictionaries
  I hope you understand what I mean to say
  Note:- The unit testing and the data structures example were taken from the answers provided to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

(I recommend this answer over my long answer as it's less likely to go out of date & points you to those more knowledgable than myself)

Read: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/02/recommended-reading-for-developers.html

Do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503239/good-c-sharp-open-source-projects-to-participate-in

Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/

---

**Long Answer**

(based on the revised question)

Depending where you want to get to, different answers are applicable.  e.g. Programming computer games takes a very different skillset to programming websites, and there are non technical skills to consider around working with others, delivering on promises, creating customer confidence, etc.

With that in mind, ensure you define for yourself what your target is, work towards that, but regularly review things to ensure you're on track for your target, and that the target you set initially is the one you're hoping to reach.

- Test Driven Development (TDD) - By writing tests before you write solutions your code is structured in a more modular way.  This makes it both easier to test and simpler to maintain.  Having those tests available also lowers the risk associated with future changes, as most of your regression testing will be automated as you amend the code.
- Decoupled Design - i.e. write code with a lack of interdependencies.  Inversion of Control (IoC) and Dependency Injection are good examples of how to achieve this within an application, service oriented architecture (SOA) achieves this at a multi-system scale.  To begin with though, simply breaking your code down into classes and procedures to avoid monolithic methods will put you in good stead.
- Patterns - These are crafted solutions to generic problems.  Learning about them both helps to teach you about the solutions themselves, as well as assisting in giving you a vocabulary for identifying parts of your code, and also allowing you to see other's thought processes / approaches to solving those original problems.
  http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/
- Avoid Frameworks - For seasoned developers it's OK to pick and choose which frameworks you think are beneficial, but I'd argue that if you're learning you want to understand the core of the technology before you try to add anything else.  Once you have an understanding of what's possible with the language alone you're then in a better position to assess the benefits and issues of each framework, and can decide which you feel best to use for any particular project.  Learning frameworks whilst you're beginning will likely cause you to miss out on important things in the core language and invest time in a technology which will have expired after a few years.  Knowing the core will help you pick up new frameworks more easily later on, but won't tie you in to any particular framework.
  NB: some frameworks are unavoidable - i.e. if working with C# you'll be using the .Net Framework - so as with all rules, there are exceptions.
- Understand the Black Box - know what's going on when you write code; what interacts with what else, where does data come from, how far is the data from the processor, how much work has to be done to create a piece of information, what data is it OK to cache (remember) vs what data needs to be read from the source or recalculated each time to ensure it's not changed.

In addition to the books recommended on Jeff Atwood's Coding Horror blog, I'd also add this book: [ASP.NET MVC 4 and the Web API](http://www.apress.com/9781430249771), especially if you're doing any form of web development.  The book's only 130 pages, but unlike most programming books which focus solely on their subject matter, giving theoretical examples, this one guides you through a project that includes logging, security, the domain model and more on top of the REST services which it sets out to address.

Answer (score 2):

Learn about interfaces vs inheritance

Learn about anonymous functions/delegates/lambdas

Understand basic data structures (lists, dictionaries, arrays, tables and when to use them)

Learn about memory consumption

O(n) vs O(log n) etc.

Learn [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617934/c-sharp-progression-path)

Tons to learn and experience in any language helps but in my time C# is the best there has been for general programming.  You are very lucky!

Answer (score 2):

This is a good list of steps to take, though take it with a pinch of salt, as it is getting a little old now.

http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/11/19/10-steps-to-become-better-net-developer.html

If you can't see that link, his list is:

1. Learn Unit Testing
2. Get familiar with distributed Version Control Systems: Git or Mercurial.
3. Learn about IoC Containers: Autofac, Windsor Container and StructureMap.
4. Contribute to Open Source Projects of your choice.
5. Learn about Continuous Integration and try setting up TeamCity, Hudson or CruiseControl.NET.
6. Learn about NHibernate Object Relational Mapper, but be prepared to outgrow it for NoSQL persistence like CouchDB, MongoDB or RavenDB.
7. Check out the buzz about cloud computing, try Windows Azure Platform and also give a shot to running your .NET App with Mono on Linux (some free offers to try).
8. Familiarize yourself with messaging architectures and try NServiceBus, MassTransit or RhinoQueues; then learn about alternative to MSMQ - AMQP and RabbitMQ.
9. Read Domain-Driven Design and apply it in your projects.
10. Get Started with CQRS Architectures and practice it in a learning project.

He recommends you do them in order, but you can do Number 9 any time you want, and I thoroughly recommend it.